# Hosting Private GIT Repository on Windows Server using Git extension and gitolite

Tags: git, github, gitolite, git-extensions

I need to create Private GIT Repository on Windows Server (Host will be windows server and client will be windows 7 )using Git extension and gitolite for fine grain control on repository and with only open source software( if required).

Also is it possible to have such arrangement without SSH as I am going to implement it in my personal network only. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have it running for multiple repos under WS12R2 using cygwin, lmk if you want me to write it up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of git servers for windows which you can install.
All of the latest version support multiple [transfer protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols).

Read about the protocols here: 
[Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols).

When you install the server unable the `http/https` protocols and you will not to use `ssh`.

For windows server you can use this:
https://bonobogitserver.com/

[image]

Comment: @AdityaV Maybe a late question, did you find an alternative in the end? I am running to the same problem, i need to host a Private GIT repo  on windows server. but Bonoboo does not give me any fine graned solution.

Comment: @Jan Van Looveren due to constraint of time I moved to ubuntu os with git lab. Its stable you can assign rights based on created groups.